# How to set content in constraint layout in a fixed ratio android studio java?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-xml, android-cardview

**My cardview is placed just below the ImageView in constraintlayout.  I want cardview to start by overlapping the bottom 5 percent of the ImageView upto the content of the cardview.**

Currently my layout looks like this. [image: current layout]

And i want it to look like this. [image: required layout]

Below is my code..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/parentContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/textColor">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/backgroundImage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cardView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.3"/>

    <!-- CardView: Starts from the bottom 10% of the ImageView -->
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/backgroundImage"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/signupText"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="30dp"
        app:cardElevation="20dp">

        <!-- CardView content here -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="24dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/esign"
                android:textAlignment="center" />
               
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/username"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="8dp"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/Id"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="8dp"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/pin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="8dp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/loginButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/my_gradient_2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="SIGN IN"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:cornerRadius="20dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView> 
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

How can i make cardview to start by overlapping the bottom 5 percent of the imageview like the second image.

Answer (score 0):

*Just try - please check*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/parentContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp">
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_8sdp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="24dp">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_person"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textAlignment="center" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/username"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:hint="Please enter username"
                android:background="@drawable/gradient_stroke"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="10dp"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/Id"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:hint="Please enter id"
                android:background="@drawable/gradient_stroke"
                android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="8dp"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/pin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:hint="Please enter pin"
                android:background="@drawable/gradient_stroke"
                android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="8dp"/>
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/loginButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_capture"
                android:drawableTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:background="@drawable/gradient_stroke"
                android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="SIGN IN"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:cornerRadius="20dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_15sdp"
        android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:text="Please sign-up"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_16ssp"
        android:layout_below="@id/cardView"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Comment: what is @dimen/_16ssp. Cannot resolve symbol '@dimen/_10sdp' . Do i have to create it or what? please let me know.

Comment: //sdp
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.1.0'